# IPhone 6 left out in sun

Tags: iphone

I left my iphone 6 in the sun and it stopped working.  It has been a few hours since I cooled it down and it still doesn't work or even take a charge.  Is the battery damaged?  How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let the phone cool down for a couple of hours (place it by a fan), then plug it into your Mac and **hold down the iPhone's power button and home button together for 20 seconds for hard reset.**

You could try the hard reset first, if you choose.